# Compares strings if containing sub-strings whatever the order

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say we have a string such as

```
AABBCCDDEEFFGG
```

It contains 7 sub-strings

```
AA BB CC DD EE FF GG
```

Now let's reorganize the order as long as the new string contains the sub-strings, then we think that they are equal. The new string is

```
AACCFFGGEEBBDD
```

It just was changed the order as

```
AA CC FF GG EE BB DD
```

I have many combinations from sub-strings. Each sub-string has exactly two chars. How can I compare the long string as same in stored procedure? Let say the old string is from database, the new one is from input parameter.

Comment: How do you define "substring"? Is it just two consecutive characters?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a function which splits the strings and compares the strings.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compare_str (
     p_str1 VARCHAR2,
     p_str2 VARCHAR2
) RETURN INTEGER AS
     TYPE strytype IS
          TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
     str_t1   strytype;
     str_t2   strytype;
BEGIN
     SELECT substr(p_str1, (level - 1) * 2 + 1,2) AS ch BULK COLLECT
        INTO str_t1
     FROM dual CONNECT BY
          level <= length(p_str1) / 2
     ORDER BY ch;

     SELECT substr(p_str2, (level - 1) * 2 + 1,2) AS ch BULK COLLECT
     INTO str_t2
     FROM dual CONNECT BY
          level <= length(p_str2) / 2
     ORDER BY ch;

     IF str_t1 = str_t2
     THEN
          RETURN 1;
     ELSE
          RETURN 0;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

So, In your queries or procedures, you may simply call the function passing the appropriate columns / strings as arguments.

```
select compare_str('AABBCCDDEEFFGG','AACCFFGGEEBBDD') from dual;

1
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31a3933ff11a8fc5fccd19f28fa6e09e)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below

```
create or replace function str_comparison ( i_String1 varchar2, i_String2 varchar2 )
                     return pls_integer is
  o_result pls_integer;
begin
  with t(str1,str2) as
  (
   select i_String1, i_String2 from dual
  ), t2(s_str1,s_str2) as
  (
  select substr(str1,-2*level,2),
         substr(str2,-2*level,2)
    from t
   connect by level <= length(str1)/2
  ), t3 as
  (
  select listagg(s_str1) within group ( order by s_str1 )
         as str1,
         listagg(s_str2) within group ( order by s_str2 )
         as str2
    from t2
  )
  select decode(str1,str2,1,0)
    into o_result
    from t3;

  return o_result;
end;
```

and see substitution `AACCFFGGEEBBDD` and `AABBCCDDEEFFGG` for the arguments yield `1` showing those strings are identical whenever ordered due to your logic, otherwise you get `0` (zero).